# Error al abrir mi Activity con un RecyclerView conectado a Firebase Firestore

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, kotlin, recyclerview

estoy haciendo una app que utiliza un recycler view en una activity y la información la saco desde Firebase Firestore .Pero cuando abro esa activity se cierra la app. Paso el error que me salta cuando se cierra.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.ezdev.chepesdelivery, PID: 23947
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ezdev.chepesdelivery.Repo$getTiendaData$1.onSuccess(Repo.kt:18)
    at com.ezdev.chepesdelivery.Repo$getTiendaData$1.onSuccess(Repo.kt:7)
    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzn.run(Unknown Source:4)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Creo que el error se produce por culpa del Repo, Paso el código del Repo.

```
package com.ezdev.chepesdelivery

import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore

class Repo {

    fun getTiendaData():LiveData<MutableList<Tiendas>>{
        val mutableData = MutableLiveData<MutableList<Tiendas>>()
        FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("tiendasOnline").get().addOnSuccessListener { result ->
            val listData = mutableListOf<Tiendas>()
            for(document in result){
                val imageUrl = document.getString("Url")
                val nombre =  document.getString("Nombre")
                val online = document.getBoolean("Online")
                val descripcion = document.getString("Descripcion")
                val tienda = Tiendas(nombre!!, descripcion!!, online!!, imageUrl!!)
                listData.add(tienda)
            }
            mutableData.value = listData
        }

        return  mutableData
    }


}
```

EL programa compila bien pero cuando se lanza la activity se cierra la app. estoy usando Kotlin

Muchas gracias desde ya.

edit: Aqui agrego el activity main (RestaurantesActivity).

```
package com.ezdev.chepesdelivery

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_restaurantes.*

class RestaurantesActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var adapter:MyAdapter
    private val viewModel by lazy { ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyViewModel::class.java)}


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_restaurantes)

        adapter = MyAdapter(this)

        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        observeData()


    }

    fun observeData(){
        viewModel.fetchTiendaData().observe(this, Observer {

            adapter.setListData(it)
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

        })
    }

}
```

Tambien paso el codigo del ViewModel

```
package com.ezdev.chepesdelivery

import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel

class MyViewModel: ViewModel() {

    val repo = Repo()

    fun fetchTiendaData():LiveData<MutableList<Tiendas>>{

        val mutableData = MutableLiveData<MutableList<Tiendas>>()
        repo.getTiendaData().observeForever {
            mutableData.value = it
        }

        return mutableData

    }

}
```

El recycler View funcionaba bien, hasta que agregue la parte del codigo que lo conecta con Firebase

Bueno, espero que me puedan ayudar porque no logro saber como solucionarlo, es un problema que no me salio nunca.

Este es todo el logcat desde que inicio la app. El logcat esta a nivel verbose.

```
2021-05-21 23:33:09.390 5094-5094/? I/.chepesdeliver: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
2021-05-21 23:33:09.415 5094-5094/? I/.chepesdeliver: Unquickening 12 vdex files!
2021-05-21 23:33:09.417 5094-5094/? W/.chepesdeliver: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2021-05-21 23:33:09.608 5094-5094/com.ezdev.chepesdelivery D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2021-05-21 23:33:09.609 5094-5094/com.ezdev.chepesdelivery D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2021-05-21 23:33:09.645 5094-5094/com.ezdev.chepesdelivery I/FirebaseApp: Device unlocked: initializing all Firebase APIs for app [DEFAULT]
2021-05-21 23:33:09.663 5094-5094/com.ezdev.chepesdelivery I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
2021-05-21 23:33:09.680 5094-5126/com.ezdev.chepesdelivery D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
2021-05-21 23:33:09.682 5094-5126/com.ezdev.chepesdelivery D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
2021-05-21 23:33:09.683 5094-5125/com.ezdev.chepesdelivery I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to fallback implementation
2021-05-21 23:33:09.683 5094-5126/com.ezdev.chepesdelivery D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
2021-05-21 23:33:09.711 5094-5094/com.ezdev.chepesdelivery W/.chepesdeliver: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2021-05-21 23:33:09.718 5094-5094/com.ezdev.chepesdelivery W/.chepesdeliver: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2021-05-21 23:33:09.838 5094-5123/com.ezdev.chepesdelivery D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xe8b9dc10, tid 5123
2021-05-21 23:33:09.842 5094-5123/com.ezdev.chepesdelivery D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_async_frame_commands ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0 
2021-05-21 23:33:09.844 5094-5123/com.ezdev.chepesdelivery W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
2021-05-21 23:33:09.868 5094-5123/com.ezdev.chepesdelivery D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xe8ba2670: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
2021-05-21 23:33:09.895 5094-5123/com.ezdev.chepesdelivery D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe8ba2670: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe8ef7d10) (first time)
2021-05-21 23:33:09.910 5094-5123/com.ezdev.chepesdelivery I/Gralloc4: mapper 4.x is not supported
2021-05-21 23:33:09.912 5094-5123/com.ezdev.chepesdelivery D/HostConnection: createUnique: call
2021-05-21 23:33:09.912 5094-5123/com.ezdev.chepesdelivery D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xe8ba2bb0, tid 5123
2021-05-21 23:33:09.913 5094-5123/com.ezdev.chepesdelivery D/goldfish-address-space: allocate: Ask for block of size 0x100
2021-05-21 23:33:09.913 5094-5123/com.ezdev.chepesdelivery D/goldfish-address-space: allocate: ioctl allocate returned offset 0x3fb832000 size 0x2000
2021-05-21 23:33:09.952 5094-5123/com.ezdev.chepesdelivery D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_async_frame_commands ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0 
2021-05-21 23:33:19.188 5094-5479/com.ezdev.chepesdelivery W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found.
2021-05-21 23:33:19.194 5094-5479/com.ezdev.chepesdelivery I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module providerinstaller:0 and remote module providerinstaller:0
2021-05-21 23:33:19.194 5094-5479/com.ezdev.chepesdelivery W/ProviderInstaller: Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
2021-05-21 23:33:19.210 5094-5478/com.ezdev.chepesdelivery I/TetheringManager: registerTetheringEventCallback:com.ezdev.chepesdelivery
2021-05-21 23:33:19.230 5094-5479/com.ezdev.chepesdelivery I/.chepesdeliver: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
2021-05-21 23:33:19.234 5094-5479/com.ezdev.chepesdelivery I/.chepesdeliver: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
2021-05-21 23:33:19.253 5094-5479/com.ezdev.chepesdelivery I/.chepesdeliver: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
2021-05-21 23:33:19.254 5094-5479/com.ezdev.chepesdelivery D/nativeloader: classloader namespace configured for unbundled product apk. library_path=/product/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib/x86:/product/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/PrebuiltGmsCore.apk!/lib/x86:/product/lib:/system/product/lib
2021-05-21 23:33:19.258 5094-5479/com.ezdev.chepesdelivery W/.chepesdeliver: Accessing hidden field Ldalvik/system/BaseDexClassLoader;->pathList:Ldalvik/system/DexPathList; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2021-05-21 23:33:19.258 5094-5479/com.ezdev.chepesdelivery W/.chepesdeliver: Accessing hidden field Ldalvik/system/DexPathList;->nativeLibraryDirectories:Ljava/util/List; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2021-05-21 23:33:19.258 5094-5479/com.ezdev.chepesdelivery W/.chepesdeliver: Accessing hidden field Ldalvik/system/DexPathList;->systemNativeLibraryDirectories:Ljava/util/List; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2021-05-21 23:33:19.258 5094-5479/com.ezdev.chepesdelivery W/.chepesdeliver: Accessing hidden field Ldalvik/system/DexPathList;->nativeLibraryPathElements:[Ldalvik/system/DexPathList$NativeLibraryElement; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2021-05-21 23:33:19.259 5094-5479/com.ezdev.chepesdelivery W/.chepesdeliver: Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/DexPathList;->makePathElements(Ljava/util/List;)[Ldalvik/system/DexPathList$NativeLibraryElement; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2021-05-21 23:33:19.260 5094-5479/com.ezdev.chepesdelivery V/NativeCrypto: Registering com/google/android/gms/org/conscrypt/NativeCrypto's 286 native methods...
2021-05-21 23:33:19.267 5094-5479/com.ezdev.chepesdelivery W/.chepesdeliver: Accessing hidden method Ljava/security/spec/ECParameterSpec;->getCurveName()Ljava/lang/String; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2021-05-21 23:33:19.453 5094-5479/com.ezdev.chepesdelivery I/ProviderInstaller: Installed default security provider GmsCore_OpenSSL
2021-05-21 23:33:20.541 5094-5491/com.ezdev.chepesdelivery W/.chepesdeliver: Accessing hidden field Ljava/net/Socket;->impl:Ljava/net/SocketImpl; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2021-05-21 23:33:20.543 5094-5491/com.ezdev.chepesdelivery W/.chepesdeliver: Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->get()Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard; (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
2021-05-21 23:33:20.546 5094-5491/com.ezdev.chepesdelivery W/.chepesdeliver: Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->open(Ljava/lang/String;)V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
2021-05-21 23:33:20.551 5094-5491/com.ezdev.chepesdelivery W/.chepesdeliver: Accessing hidden field Ljava/io/FileDescriptor;->descriptor:I (greylist, JNI, allowed)
2021-05-21 23:33:20.634 5094-5491/com.ezdev.chepesdelivery W/.chepesdeliver: Accessing hidden method Ljava/security/spec/ECParameterSpec;->setCurveName(Ljava/lang/String;)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2021-05-21 23:33:20.656 5094-5491/com.ezdev.chepesdelivery W/.chepesdeliver: Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/BlockGuard;->getThreadPolicy()Ldalvik/system/BlockGuard$Policy; (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
2021-05-21 23:33:20.656 5094-5491/com.ezdev.chepesdelivery W/.chepesdeliver: Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/BlockGuard$Policy;->onNetwork()V (greylist, linking, allowed)
2021-05-21 23:33:21.366 5094-5094/com.ezdev.chepesdelivery D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2021-05-21 23:33:21.366 5094-5094/com.ezdev.chepesdelivery E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.ezdev.chepesdelivery, PID: 5094
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.ezdev.chepesdelivery.Repo$getTiendaData$1.onSuccess(Repo.kt:18)
        at com.ezdev.chepesdelivery.Repo$getTiendaData$1.onSuccess(Repo.kt:7)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzn.run(Unknown Source:4)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Comment: Muestra el código de la activity más líneas del stacktrace.

Comment: Ya actualice con los demas codigos, gracias por ayudarme

Comment: Puedes agregar también más lineas del error?

Comment: esas son las unicas lineas que me salen en rojo

Comment: Busca bien, abajo tiene que haber más. La importante es la que dice `caused by`

Comment: agregue algo mas de lo que saco el logcat, si podes decirme donde buscar mas info avisame

Comment: Aún no es suficiente pero escribí la respuesta más probable. No puedo confirmar que ese sea tu prublema sin ver el stack trace completo. Así que avísame si no funciona

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seguramente estás escribiendo mal el nombre de alguno de los campos y por lo tanto obtienes `null`. Puedes solucionarlo agregandoles un default value

```
fun getTiendaData(): LiveData<MutableList<Tiendas>> {
    val mutableData = MutableLiveData<MutableList<Tiendas>>()
    FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("tiendasOnline").get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { result ->
            mutableData.value = result.documents.map { snap ->
                snap.run {
                    Tiendas(
                        getString("Nombre") ?: "default",
                        getString("Descripcion") ?: "default",
                        getBoolean("Online") ?: true,
                        getString("Url") ?: "default",
                    )
                }
            }.toMutableList()
        }
    return mutableData
}
```

Comment: Realize los cambios que mencionaste pero sigue ocurriendo el mismo error, no se si es importante pero tengo el tutorial donde sigo estos pasos. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y09spGIkAlg

Comment: sería mas fácil si pudiera ver más líneas del stack strace. Coloca el logcat en nivel `Verbose` y trata de buscar más información

Comment: esa es todo el logcat desde que inicio mi app

Comment: Algo anda mal con tu logcat, definitavamente te está ocultando información. Pero creo que puedo adivinar. Escribiré la respuesta más probable

Comment: Prueba eso. Y no te recomiendo seguir ese tutorial. El que lo hace no parece tener mucha experienca o por lo menos no sigue buenas prácticas.

Comment: Era eso, muchas gracias encerio. Ahora vere como agregarle un boton. Te lo agredesco mucho

Comment: Lee [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)